# Animate cluster of markerclusterer

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I am using Google Maps v3 with MarkerClustererPlus. [Click for docs](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.9/docs/reference.html)

I want to animate a cluster if a cluster contains a specific marker. The animation is quite easy if the marker is not inside a cluster.

```
  marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
```

But i want to bounce the whole cluster-icon. I can get the cluster with:

```
  markerCluster.getClusters();
```

But how can i associate the cluster-div with my getClusters()-Array? I dont know which div belongs to which cluster from the getClusters()-function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not possible via the documented methods/properties, but you may get access to these properties.

- **Step #1:** Each cluster has a  `markers_` -property, which is an array that contains all the markers of the cluster. Iterate over all clusters and check if the `markers`_-array contains the  wanted marker
- **Step #2:** when you've found the cluster with the wanted marker, access the property `clusterIcon_.div_` of the cluster, that's the element that represents the cluster-icon

  ```
  //attach listener to clusteringend-event
  google.maps.event.addListener(markerClustererInstance,'clusteringend',function(){

  //iterate over all clusters
  var clusters=this.getClusters();
  for(var i = 0; i < clusters.length;++i){

  if(clusters[i].markers_.length > 1 
        && clusters[i].clusterIcon_.div_){

          // clusters[i].clusterIcon_.div_ is the HTMLElement
          // that contains the wanted clusterIcon,
          // you should at first reset here recently applied changes

          if(clusters[i].markers_.indexOf(wantedMarker)>-1){
            //the marker has been found, do something with it
          } 
    }
  }});
  ```

  **But Note:** The cluster-icon is not a `google.maps.Marker`, you can't simply apply an animation  as you may do it with a native marker. Furthermore: Animations that will modify the position of the cluster-icon (e.g. bounce) may interfere with the markerClusterer, I would suggest to use effects that can be applied via color-changes or changes of the background-image(the cluster-icons you see are the background-images of the div).

Comment: I actually have a similar issue. I got my cluster animating by adding a class to its div_ (css3 animation). However, the issue arises when a user zoom in/out the animation stop because the clusters have been reset hence the added classes are gone. I've tried to keep track of the marker inside the cluster that I want to animate, then upon zoom which trigger 'clusteringend' I will re-add that class. However, that didn't work out... :( How can I prevent the animation from stopping after zoom in/out?